# How to check the perl environment variables used in the script before executing?

Tags: perl

How to know that the environment used in the script  is the same that the program will see when it runs?. 
Perl stores the environment in %ENV to my knowledge.

i am trying to use the code which is mentioned below in order to know the variables.

```
    require Data::Dumper;
    print STDERR Data::Dumper::Dumper( \%ENV );
```

Is there any  procudure to check the env variables used before the script starts executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're getting at, but you can put your code inside a `BEGIN` block to see what your environment variables are before any modules you use are loaded.

```
BEGIN {
    require Data::Dumper;
    print STDERR Data::Dumper::Dumper( \%ENV );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The contents of `%ENV` are inherited to any process you execute from a perl script.

If you're concerned that a child process reads sensitive information from your environment, give it a clean one before running it:

```
do {
    local %ENV;
    $ENV{PATH} = '/usr/bin';
    system './another-binary';
};
```